# Pooled OLS with industry specific effects (reghdfe)

Tags: stata, panel-data

I have a panel dataset for multiple firms throughout 8 years and I'm trying to use a pooled OLS with industry-specific effects with the `reghdfe' command to control for a categorical variable (NAICS Industry Code). I typed

```
reghdfe DV IV control variables i.year, absorb(NAICS Industry Code)
```

Is this the correct way to use the command? Is it correct to use `i.year` within the variables or should I add it to the absorbed variables?

In addition I'm using a Fixed Effect Panel Regression and control for clustered standard errors. Do I have to control for clustered standard errors in the `reghdfe` as well or is it sufficient to just do it within the fixed effect panel regression?

Answer (score 1):

You should include your variable `year` in the `absorb()` option to catch the intended use of `reghdfe`:

```
reghdfe y x, absorb(naics year)
```

Alternatively, you can also use `reg y x i.naics i.year`.

I assume NAICS codes to be numeric; otherwise, you might need to transform the variable to numeric, e.g. using `egen num_naics= group(naics)`.

---

*Note:* The R-squared rests on different assumptions and might differ between the two commands.

*Note_2:* If your question is specifically about coding, everyone is better off when you provide example data. Statistical questions might be better suited for Cross Validated.