# Fixed effects with year, country and sector effects

Tags: stata

I did the Hausman test in my data and this showed me that I may use fixed effects. However, when I did the fixed effects without any year, country, and sector effects, I get the results that I hope to get (a statistically and positive significant relation with the variables):

`xtreg price_outliers esg_score_w roa_w eps_w bv_pershare_w lev_w size_w, fe`

However, when I use `i.year`, `i.country` and `i.ec_sector`, I get a negative relation with the same variables:

`xtreg price_outliers esg_score_w roa_w eps_w bv_pershare_w lev_w size_w i.year i.country i.ec_sector`

What could be the reason for this?

Comment: The first command is a FE regression and the second command is a RE regression with dummies. You maybe want to compare the first command with "reg Y X". For more info see: https://www.princeton.edu/~otorres/Panel101.pdf

Comment: Using the command with ", fe"I am only controlling for id effects because I used "xtset id year", right?
I want to control also for year, country and industry effects, should am I use fixed effects and control for this variables or should I use pooled OLS with dummies?
If I should use fixed effects, what is the right command to perform this controlling effects?

Answer (score 0):

A common way of including multiple fixed effects is with `reghdfe`, available from SSC and written by S. Correia. Here is the documentation: http://scorreia.com/help/reghdfe.html.

Code:

```
ssc install reghdfe
reghdfe price_outliers esg_score_w roa_w eps_w bv_pershare_w lev_w size_w, absorb(year country ec_sector)
```

That said, `reg ... i.year i.country i.ec_sector`, i.e. the pooled OLS version with dummies, should yield virtually identical results. Also see: [Pooled OLS with industry specific effects (reghdfe)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67924090/pooled-ols-with-industry-specific-effects-reghdfe/67924696#67924696)